# VS 2010 keep stating that "This using directive is not required"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

The following using statements in a regular class keeps screaming at me that "The using directive is not required".

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
```

Yet if I try to use the `DateTime` data type intellisense will not pick it up and the compiler complains when I try to build.

Comment: Well to use `DateTime` you only need the last one... could you give a short but complete example? What *exactly* is "screaming" at you?

Comment: Can you put a little more of your code?  I know this is a dummy check but sometimes it may happen. Did you check to see if there is a ! on your System reference? Or maybe for some reason the path of the reference got jacked up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could organize them:

[image]

Then when you want to use a new type in your code which is not in your usings declarations simply place the cursor over it and <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F10+Enter</kbd>

This being said, organizing and removing unused usings is not compulsory. This has already been discussed here. It has strictly no difference at runtime nor at the emitted assembly. You should do it only if you are anal about how your source code looks like and have things properly organized. I do it all the time.

Comment: organize Usings removes unwanted imports also? I was unaware of that. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a misunderstanding of how VS 2010 works. The IDE tells you that you're not using a library until you actually type the code that requires the library.

I thought the errors were being generated after I build the solution. The "organize usings" menu item in the context menu helps clean this issue up quick. Thanks for all your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Vs is telling you that you have added some libraries that are no required. remove the not used libraries and make a clean solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are getting this error for `using System;` statement. Try removing that statement.